# Disbursing $500,000 over 240 months at an interest rate of 3.5%

Tags: finance

I'm trying to determine what the monthly payouts would be based on the following information.

*Starting Amount:* $\$500,000$

*Interest Rate:* $3.5%$ monthly

Deplete over $20$ years ($240$ months)

How much will be disbursed from this account each month? Can this be distributed evenly over each month?

I've tried the following with the accompanying table:

Check Amount = Amount / Months Remaining

Amount = (Prior Month Amount - Prior Month Check Amount) + (Prior Month Amount * Interest Rate)

| Months Remaining | Amount | Interest | Check Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 240 | 500000.00 | 0.035 | 2083.34 |
| 239 | 515416.67 | 0.035 | 2156.56 |
| 238 | 531299.69 | 0.035 | 2232.35 |

With each month, the Amount Remaining continues to grow. This is wrong as I am looking to deplete the account to 0 over 20 years.

Comment: This is a classic annuity problem. Find an annuity with the given interest and duration with a present value of 500k.

Comment: Based on the annuity formula, I am getting a value of $2,899.80 per month. Does this sound correct? @Magdiragdag

Comment: That is not even close to correct. 3.5% of 500000 is 17500 and then you're not even depleting the principal.

Comment: @Magdiragdag 

    P = ((0.035/12)*500,000) / (1 - (1 + (0.035/12)) ^-240) =$2,899.80

Am I incorrectly determining the value for r?

Comment: Where does the /12 come from? Your interest rate is 3.5% per month and that is also what you use in your table. If your interest rate is really 3.5%/12 per month - which is much more reasonable - then you immediately have a reason why your account remaining grows in your table: you're computing the wrong interest. Using that, and assuming you're withdrawing at the end of every month, 2899.80 is correct.